# How to create correct HELP page for GET request with Dictionary parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, get, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Search method in my API controller. It is a GET request with input parameter of Dictionary keyValuePairs.

Code is something like this.

```
[Route("Search")] 
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Search( Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs)
 {

  IDictionary<string, object> resultDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();  
  var keyValueParameters = this.Url.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();           

//Do bunch of things with keyValueParameters and fill up resultDict 

   return Ok(resultDict);

  }
```

Help page is as follow.
[image: Request]

[image: Response]
 Where you can see Body Parameters in Request Information but not for Response Information. Shouldn't it be other way around for GET. 
I am sure I need to handle this little differently given dictionaries involved but not able to figure it out.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what are you using to generate that web page UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the Helper pages are using pretty common ApiExplorer package. I did not try it myself but you can add something like this to your code to make it understand what is the correct response there:

```
[ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(IDictionary<string, object>), statusCode: StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IHttpActionResult Search( Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. ResponseType attribute took care of problem with Response information but Request is still same. There should be something similar to tell help generator that there is a dictionary type in request parameter.

Comment: @user2918107 I'm not sure what you mean, basically, it's already there - you have the dictionary as the parameter type and it's appeared on the helper page. Do you mean there are several media type formatters there and you would want just one? Then try to use `[Consumes("application/json")]` attribute to achieve only one media type formatter.

Comment: My Search is a GET request. I think it should not show Dictionary in body paramters. It should be in URI parameters. Currently, helper page is saying URI parameters None and Dictionary in Body parameters.

Comment: @user2918107 you may try add this:
`public IHttpActionResult Search( [FromRoute] Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs)`

Comment: Thanks so much for it. Everything is correct now. Is there a way to just show 'Search' instead of whole thing Search?keyValuePairs[0].key={keyValuePairs[0].key}&keyValuePairs[0].value={keyValuePairs[0].value}&keyValuePairs[1].key={keyValuePairs[1].key}&keyValuePairs[1].value={keyValuePairs[1].value}